# Is it possible to add some custom building tasks while compiling Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, yeoman

For example I have Dynamic Web Project where **backend** done in Java while **frontend** written in AngularJS. Is it possible in a time of compiling merge multiple JavaScript files into single file, minify it and automatically add dependency to it and remove dependency to source files?

As I understand there are build tools like [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which has such functionality, but how can I use them together with Eclipse?

Thank you.

Comment: No, I haven't used Ant and as far as I know it useful only for Java code, not sure can it help with JavaScript projects.

Comment: Not actualy, Ant can be used in Javascript projects.Use ant, it is an awesome tool and it can be matched with Eclipse

Comment: I was ready to happily edit my answer to show how to use Ant in a JavaScript project in Eclipse, I like to humbly suggest to add a comment when you didn't recieve your answer out of the Q/As.  I still suggest to don't use anything on her than Ant and the Ant and all of the apaches command line tools are layer d products and can be used in eclipse, do a simple google search. Good luck

Comment: Were the articles useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach custom Ant build steps to the build process of any project in Eclipse, independent of whether it is a Java, web or other project. To do so, add an [Ant builder](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-93_project_builder.htm) via project -> project settings -> builders and tweak the settings of that builder, so that the script is automatically executed on every file change in your project.

Comment: I have only one question, why not Gradle? Actually after @Iman has answered I made some investigation and came to decision (based on people reviews) that Gradle is better option but I haven't tried it yet, neither Ant. And you were right, I didn't understand from **Iman** answer that I can make a custom builder in Eclipse, was sure that it's command line tool only.

Comment: My answer is not about which build tool is better to generate your needed artifacts. It is about what is available in Eclipse for automatically triggering additional build steps for _every_ project (independent of its preferred built technology). If you don't need any scripting, but just want to invoke a single command line to execute a gradle build, then you can also attach a "Command" builder the same way as described above and just give it the command line for invoking gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ant,
Take look at the following post which shows Ant can be used with JavaScript

http://addyosmani.com/blog/client-side-build-process/

And install Ant plugin for your eclipse using this installation guide

https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/install.html

To use Ant in Eclipse for you Javascript project take a look at the following link :

http://steveperkins.com/injecting-javascript-into-ant-builds/

Comment: This doesn't have any Eclipse specific advice, as requested by the OP.

Comment: @Bananeweizen Yes you are right, I forgot to describe how to use Ant against eclipse. But there is a lot of complete tutorial for this on the Web, I suggest him a tool to do what he wants to do in Eclipse. You also wrote a brief hint for him.

Comment: @Bananeweizen Now I have a full set! I still don't know why Gradle (or Groovy) or jruby when apache has an old polished, bug free, powerfull product, I suggest you Bananewezen to read the last link, would be interesting it supposes